# process pool: adding a process automatically once one of the process is completed

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I have a function which creates a "pool" of process and executes each of the process in the pool.

```
def sendAndExecutePybotTests(poolProcessNum):
    fullList = _generatePybotList()
    print fullList
    pool = [fullList[i:i+int(poolProcessNum)] for i in range(0, len(fullList), int(poolProcessNum))]
    for chunk in pool:
        procs = []
        for executeLine in chunk:
            proc = Process(target=_executePybotTest, args=(executeLine,))
            procs.append(proc)
            # time interval=1 second for each suite
            time.sleep(1)
            proc.start()

        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
```

The executePybotTest (which just calls a subprocess to execute a command):

```
def _executePybotTest(executeLine):    
    subprocess.call(executeLine,shell=True)
```

I am using this to run automation tests in parallel. But because of this pool being joined it waits for all the processes inside the pool to finish to continue on to other items waiting to be executed.

I was looking into implementing a queue and automatically executing the next one in queue once one of the processes in the pool is finished. I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `multiprocessing` to create/manage the [Pool of processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), and use [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) to distribute the list of tests to processes in the pool. Then each process can execute the test as it receives them. The `map` method handles distributing the tasks to each process in the pool for you, so you don't have to deal with implementing it yourself.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def execute_test(input):
    print("executing test " + input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    full_list = _generatePybotList()
    p = Pool(poolProcessNum)
    p.map(execute_test, full_list)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, This works perfectly for me! @dano